# Switching branches each with local changes

Tags: git

Imagine there are 2 branches: *master* and *feature*. Now I work on a new feature and hence have that branch checked out. Later I need to work on *master* but cannot commit the *feature* changes since they are not yet in a good state. I can stage them and switch to *master*. I do some work there and suddenly I get an idea I need to test in the *feature* branch, so I want to switch to it, but again I have to stage the local changes in *master*.

Now imagine you have 10 instead of 1 feature branch. Is it the only way to stash all local changes when switching branches or is there a more intelligent solution?

Please don't question the work flow, it's just an expample to accentuate the annoying **work** - **stash** - **checkout** - **work** - **stash** - **checkout** - **apply stash** - **work** - **stash** - **checkout** - **apply other stash** -... cycle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to check-in. Don't stash, just check-in whatever you have on the feature branch before you switch to another branch or to master. Leave a nice descriptive commit message. You're thinking in terms of centralized source control, where checking-in incomplete or unfinished work will cause problems for others. But this is Git - it's your local copy of the repository. You're inconveniencing no-one by checking-in, and you don't have to push changes to origin to check-out another branch.

Comment: You are absolutely right, I had my remote branch in mind for feature work which I don't need at all since I do feature dev only locally in that specific branch.

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand why you don't go ahead and commit the changes on the `feature` branch as an "interim commit". You can always switch back, and do a `git reset HEAD^` to undo the commit and continue working. I rarely use stashes myself.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of merely commiting locally, you may create new branches right before commiting, e.g:

```
[work]
$ git checkout -b sub_feature_branch
$ git commit [...]

# Now time to switch to other branch

$ git checkout other_branch
[work & repeat]
```

Doing so, not only you keep each mainstream branch (master & feature in your case) clean in case you change your mind later, but you also get the ability to postpone merge operations when applicable.

Comment: Thanks, that reminds me on the more dynamic nature of Git. Just make a local feature branch and that is it.